# How to navigate or select WPF Image with keyboard Tab key?

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, tooltip, accessibility

The WPF image is not keyboard accessible. The requirement is on tab key focus in the tooltip must open and stay till tab key focus out. How to achieve it in Xaml?

The code looks like below,

```
                                 <Image Height="17"
                                   x:Name="tabinfoIcon"
                                   Stretch="Fill"
                                   Width="17"
                                   Cursor="Hand"
                                   Margin="5">
                                <Image.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip Background="#FFFEFEFE"
                                             Foreground="#FF5E5D5D"
                                             Placement="MousePoint"
                                             x:Name="tabToolTip">
                                        <TextBlock Width="200"
                                                   Padding="10,10"
                                                   TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                                                   Text="{x:Static resx:Strings.TabToolTipText}">
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </ToolTip>
                                </Image.ToolTip>
                            </Image>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image` is not a `Control` and therefore not a tab stop or navigation target.

To solve this, you can wrap the `Image` into a `ContentControl` and use a `Popup` to show a tool tip on keyboard focus:

```
<StackPanel>
  <Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=ImagePresenter, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin, Mode=OneWay}"
         PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ImagePresenter}" 
         AllowsTransparency="True">
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Static resx:Strings.TabToolTipText}" />
  </Popup>
  <ContentControl x:Name="ImagePresenter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Image Height="100" x:Name="tabinfoIcon" 
           Stretch="Fill"
           Width="100"

           Cursor="Hand"
           Margin="5">
      <Image.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Background="#FFFEFEFE"
                 Foreground="#FF5E5D5D"
                 Placement="MousePoint"
                 x:Name="tabToolTip">
          <TextBlock Width="200"
                     Padding="10,10"
                     TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                     Text="{x:Static resx:Strings.TabToolTipText}">
          </TextBlock>
        </ToolTip>
      </Image.ToolTip>
    </Image>
  </ContentControl>
</StackPanel>
```